# VueJS - Dynamic State Management multiple instances

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am creating an app and I have a component "Message" which uses a `store` to get data back from a JSON file (this will be eventually a database) and the component is as follows:

```
export default  {
   props: ['message'],

   mounted: function() {    
       this.$store.dispatch("FETCHMESSAGE", this.message);
   },

   computed: {
       title: function() {
          return this.$store.state.message;
       }
   }
}
```

I have the following mutation:

```
FETCHMESSAGE: function (context, type)
{
     var data = json.type; // Get the data depending on the type passed in
     // COMMIT THE DATA INTO THE STORE 
}
```

And I use it as the following:

```
<MessageApp message="welcome"></MessageApp>
```

This works for the most part and the correct message is displayed. The issue is when I have multiple instances of `MessageApp` being called on the same page. They both show the same message (of the last message) being called. E.g.

```
<MessageApp message="welcome"></MessageApp>
<MessageApp message="goodbye"></MessageApp>
```

They will each show the `goodbye` message. I know why this is happening but is it possible to have multiple instances of the `store` so that this does not happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vuex is "a centralized store for all the components in an application," as the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/#what-is-vuex) say.

So imagine that you have a variable (or many) which you can use and change from all your components.

Also when you want to get properties from state, it is recommended to use [getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html).

I can't understand what you want to do, but if you want, you can have multiple states, getters, mutations and actions and use them as modules in the store ([read more](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html)). See below example from **Vuex docs**:

```js
const moduleA = {
  state: { title: '' },
  mutations: { changeTitle(state, payload) { state.title = payload } },
  actions: { changeTitle({commit}, payload) { commit('changeTitle', payload) } },
  getters: { getTitle(state) { return state.title } }
}

const moduleB = {
  state: { title: '' },
  mutations: { changeTitle(state, payload) { state.title = payload } },
  actions: { changeTitle({commit}, payload) { commit('changeTitle', payload) } },
  getters: { getTitle(state) { return state.title } }
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    a: moduleA,
    b: moduleB
  }
})

store.state.a // -> `moduleA`'s state
store.state.b // -> `moduleB`'s state
```

Comment: thanks for this however I'm looking for an effective way when calling this `dispatch` and then the `computed` this way looks like I would have to use if statements to determine which store to call?

Comment: but i cant understand what you want to do.It is weird.It looks that you are using the vuex store in wrong way.Why you store the prop you get,in vuex store,and then again you retrieve it from there?it is weird for me

Comment: As i can understand from you question you want to use the MessageApp component to show the message you are passing as props.If that the case then you dont have why to use vuex.Just display the props as soon as they are ready.